# How to delete a first and second line in each cell of column in csv

Tags: python, csv

I didnt find solution for it, so maybe someone can help me

I have an csv file and it has "splitted_text" column, how can I delete the first and second line of text in each row?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NbiY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, I'm assuming that by:

> delete the first and second line of text

you mean "delete the first and second element of each list contained in the `splitter_text` column"

In which case, you can simply apply a function along the column:

```py
df["clean_splitted_text"] = df["splitted_text"].apply(lambda x: x[2:])
```

to save the cleaned output in a new column, or

```py
df["splitted_text"] = df["splitted_text"].apply(lambda x: x[2:])
```

if you want to overwrite the content of that column (!)

Here, `lambda x: x[2:]` is a function that removes the first two elements of a list. If that list has 2 or fewer elements, then it returns the empty list: `[]`.